# How can I get a loop in setup() to reset?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I have a for loop in `function setup()` which I would like to reset and run again when my game resets. The purpose of resetting the loop is to get all the objects in the array back to their start position and colour, or to just create completely new objects.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(550, 550)
  for(let i = 0; i<200; i++) {
    x = random(width)
    y = -50 - 50 * i
    r = random(15,50)
    enemies[i] = new Enemy (x, y, r)
  }
}
```

I imagine that I won't be able to do this directly since `function setup()` can only run once, so is there a workaround to get the `setup ()` for loop to reset?

Link to full code [here](https://editor.p5js.org/353703860/sketches/nhE3gxxA6) if needed

Comment: Move the relevant code to reset them to another function, say, `reset()`, and then call that from `setup()` and also call it whenever you need to reset them?

Comment: @DavidConrad that won't work since `setup()` only executes once at the start of the program

Comment: Yes, but you can call this other function, `reset()`, any time you please.

Comment: @DavidConrad THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH. It actually freaking worked. I might actually sleep tonight. Thanks so much man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the relevant code to reset them to another function, perhaps, `reset()`. Then you can call `reset()` from `setup()`, and also call `reset()` whenever you need to reset them.